# How to render a view inside of other twig + Modal Dialog Symfony2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Today I wanna a show a [modal dialog](http://bootboxjs.com/) with a form

This is my code of main:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarPunto">
          Nueva Ronda
</button>
<div  style="display: none;"  class="modal fade" id="agregarPunto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar ronda</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 {% embed "controlidMembersBundle:Members:newRonda.html.twig" %}
                 {% endembed %}
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Crear ronda</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is the code of my view that I wanna embed

```
{% block nueva_ronda -%}
   <h1>Nueva ronda</h1>
   {{ form(form) }}
   <ul class="record_actions"></ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The trouble is when I click on the button, because I get the following error:

```php
Variable "form" does not exist in   /var/www/html/controlid/src/controlid/Bundle/MembersBundle/Resources/views/Members/newRo nda.html.twig at line 5
```

This mistake is obviusly, because I don't know how to call the controller to render the form.

This is the action on symfony  that should rendered the form

```
/*
 * @Route("/ronda/crear", name="members_ronda_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newRondaAction()
{
    $entity = new Ronda();
    $form   = $this->createRondaForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

How to embed code  inside of my [modal-dialog](http://bootboxjs.com/) to render the form?

Comment: Try passing the form to the embedded template `{% embed "controlidMembersBundle:Members:newRonda.html.twig" with {form : form} %}{% endembed %}`

Comment: @Javad not works, I get: `Variable "form" does not exist in /var/www/html/controlid/src/controlid/Bundle/MembersBundle/Resources/views/Members/showAllRondas.html.twig `

Comment: Base on the documentation for *embed* the problem might be in the `{% block nueva_ronda -%}`. Could you remove that block if it's not overridden anywhere. I also suggest to use `include` instead

Comment: The problem is the variable `form`, I don't get it, because I call first the view and not the controller

Comment: Oh, hold on; why do you return the array? Shouldn't that be a rendered view? Look at this link [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to embed the action into your twig template. Try this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ render(controller('controlidMembersBundle:Members:newRonda')) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line at the top of your template:

```
{%- use 'controlidMembersBundle:Members:newRonda.html.twig' -%}
```

JFYI you should start the bundle name with an upper case letter (Symfony standard conventions).

Then instead of embedding simply render the block with:

```
{{ block('nueva_ronda') }}
```